# How to create list with default items in SharePoint Hosted App?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have a SharePoint Hosted App. Now I am adding a new list using "**Add -> New Item -> Lists**".

List got created. But my question is, I want to add an item so that when I install my SharePoint App, the list should create with that default item.

Is this possible? If yes please suggest some work arounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it absolutely possible like the good ole days of SSOM.

Go to the your listinstance.xml >  elements.xml as below:

[image]

Then inside the xml, structure add your data as below:

```
<ListInstance Title="List1"
                OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
                TemplateType="100"
                Url="Lists/List1"
                Description="My List Instance">

    <Data>
      <Rows>
        <Row>
          <Field Name="Title">Test1</Field>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Field Name="Title">Test2</Field>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Field Name="Title">Test2</Field>
        </Row>
      </Rows>
    </Data>

  </ListInstance>
```

Here, the default values should be inside `<Data><Rows><Row>`. After that, just deploy your app and default values would be present.

[image]